# How to return the correct values at with this array format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have this array like this:

```
const tab = [
  { '1': {'id':'me'}},
  { '2': {'id':'you'}}
];
```

and I have created this function to get values from the last array like this:

```
 const ar = tab.map((user,i)=>{
  return(
      <div>
      <p>{tab[i][1].id.toString()}</p>
      </div>
    )
     });
```

Note:

I want to get the right values of the id without changing `'1'` or `'2'` 
because if I changed the `'1'` or `'2'` to `'A'` for example I can simply write `tab[i].A.id.toString()`

Comment: If you’re referencing the key by string value, use `['1']` instead.

Comment: Can you describe you problem more clearly?

Comment: thanks , it's corret , but the string inside [] are changed dynamically  this is example    const ar = tab.map((user,i)=>{
  return(
      <div>
      <p>{tab[i][''+{i}+1+''].id.toString()}</p>
      </div>
  )
});   but not working

Comment: the problem is that I need to access to the ids inside the array and the format of array are contain the element 'number' and inside each number I have other attributes and the number are changed dynamically from 1 to +550 element , I want to get the data iside these elements , when the function map fetching data I need to get the data inside each element of these that has this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```js
const tab = [
    { '1': { id: "me" }},
    { '2': { id: "you" }}
];

const ar = tab.map((user, i) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{user[(i + 1).toString()].id}</p>
        </div>
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks , but it's not in my hand right now , I have a file that contain more than 600 elements and the format of file like the example and I can't change all the file it's so difficulte so if I find a way to access to these values like that it will be more prefect.

Comment: @AzizMobarak Have a look at the new answer